# Accessing the ApplicationControler variable in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am declaring a global variable inside the ApplicationController but I try to access it from any model but when doing this the variable is empty in the model, being that in the AplicationController I am assigning a value

this is my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :base

  def base
    @empresa2 = current_usuario.empresa_id
  end
end
```

this is my model Logdatabase

```
class Logdatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  if @empresa2 == "28"
   establish_connection(:development)
  else
   establish_connection(:otrabase)
  end

end
```

Comment: Ideally, you should not try to access variables from controller in model. In MVC Architecture, separate responsibilities are given to Model, View and Controller and you should adhere to that. Even then, you want to access, post the code you tried and then try to get help from SO community

Comment: @Pramod ok I uptated post. In this case then how can I pass the ActionController variable to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would have the controller set the connection:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_database

  def set_database
    empresa2 = current_usuario.empresa_id
    configuration_name = emprase2 == '28' ? :development : :otrabase
    ActiveRecord::Base.eastablish_connection(configuration_name)
  end

end
```

However it looks like you are trying to make your production server switch dynamically between production and development databases. I wouldn't recommend this, rather setup a separate server (or if you really cannot do that then setup a second web server on the same server using a virtual server name or alternative port number)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the content of a variable to your model you define a method in your Model that accepts a parameter.

In your Empresa model:

```
def receive_variable_from_countroller(variable)
 #do what you want with the variable
end
```

In your Empresa controller:

```
#define your variable
variable = "foo"
Empresa.receive_variable_from_controller(variable)
```

I guess that would be the simplest way to do it.